# Alternative to move files

Tags: java, file-io

I wonder if there is any other way to move files from one directory to another, a snippet of my program is below. I believe there should be an efficient way to move files in java. Please take a look and respond if possible. Thanks!

```
public static void movFile(File pathFromMove,File pathToMove,File fileToMove)    //helper method 2
{

    String absPathFile2= pathToMove.getAbsolutePath() + "\\"+fileToMove.getName();                                                              //{

    InputStream inStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;

    try
    {
        //System.out.println("i am here no1");
        inStream= new FileInputStream(fileToMove);
        outStream=new FileOutputStream(absPathFile2);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];


        int length;
        while (( length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {

            outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            //System.out.println("i am here no2");

        }
      inStream.close();
        outStream.close();
        fileToMove.delete();            //to delete the original files
    //  System.out.println("i am here no3");

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        //System.out.println("i am here no4");

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: use system(), or your favorite library which hides system from you.

Answer (score 2):

If it's on the same disk, the [`File.renameTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) would be efficient

I'm not sure why you would need 3 `File` references, two should be enough...but it's your code...

For example...

```
public static void movFile(File pathFromMove,File pathToMove,File fileToMove) throws IOException {

    File from = new File(pathFromMove + File.separator + fileToMove);
    File to = new File(pathToMove+ File.separator + fileToMove);

    if (!from.renameTo(to)) {
        throw new IOException("Failed to move " + from + " to " + to);
    }

}
```

You can alos have a look at [Moving a File or Directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html) which uses the new `Paths` API available in Java 7

Comment: To suggest an NIO alternative/equivalent, check out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.file.CopyOption...)

Comment: @JoshM Added link, don't really have experience with it...still stuck in Java 6 :(

Comment: :O You appear to be 1 (2 if you count Java 8 early release) versions behind :P I'm using Java 8 and it's great, you should check it out :)

Comment: I'd like to drag our organisation into the 22nd century, but we're still using the database the company owner created 30 years ago...:'( - Don't even get me started on what they try and pass off as a client/server framework...

Comment: Haha, sounds pretty old. It must be pretty stable if your organisation never felt it was necessary for an upgrade :P

Comment: @JoshM It has no transactions, referential integrity, BLOB or CLOB, but yeah, it's awesome

Comment: thanks for the inputs. I have tried this way and it is not able to handle the IO exceptions. Please give more inputs on this.

Comment: Which `IOException`?  It will `return` `true` if it was successful or `false` if it did not, unfortunately, that's all the `File` API does